# Cannot do a pull request because branch is "identical to main"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git-branch

[image]I want to do the pull request for my `chapter_3`.

However, it states that my `main` and `chapter_3` are identical.
How to make my `chapter_3` not identical with `main`? Below i also attached my git reflog

```
$ git add .

$ git commit -m "chapter 3"
```

`$ git push origin chapter_3`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply, in your local repository, add a new commit (or now commits) to `chapter_3` and push.

Then, since `chapter_3` has new commits that `main` has not, you will be able to initiate a pull request from `chapter_3` to `main`.

The problem is: you were not on local branch chapter_3 when you did your commit. You were on `main`.

In order to avoid any mishaps, I would:

- clone the repository again
- create a chapter_3 branch
- report your work for chapter 3 there (in the new local clone)
- add commit and push

That is:

```sh
git clone https://github/com/<me>/<myRepo> newClone
cd newClone
git switch -c chapter_3
# work
git add .
git commit -m "Add chapter 3"
git push -u origin chapter_3
```

Then you can make your PR.

Notes:

- replace `<me>` by your GitHub account name, and `<myRepo>` by your target repository name. Don't use `<` and `>`: they are placeholder makers.
- replace `newClone` by a new local folder name which does not yet exist (it will be created by the `git clone` command).

Comment: may i know what the coding is? because i already try to 

git add .
git commit -m "chapter 3"
git push origin chapter_3

but the result still the same

Comment: @user16725460 git add would not be enough. You would need to commit and push as well. Can you edit your question to add the code you used so far?

Comment: @user16725460 Thank You. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: since it does not exist yet, what should i replace with? and should i do cd sample_app1 before do the git clone?

Comment: and does '#work' means that i have to do the chapter 3 again?

Comment: @user16725460 replace `newClone` by any name you want, in order to create an new folder in which you clone again your remote repository

Comment: @user16725460 And yes `#work` means: "report what changes you made for chapter 3 in that new local repository, after creating the `chapter_3` branch with `git switch -c chapter_3`.